# Designing a Low Pass Filter

Tags: remote-sensing, filter, envi, digital-image-processing, spatial-filter

How can I design a similar *Low Pass Filter* as given below which takes into account only 4-connectivity and ignores the pixels that complete 8-connectivity?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use Envi or can you use Python or R libraries?

Comment: I am only familiar with Envi but don't know how to design such type of kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt this concept and now I want to answer my own question, I wrote my answer in word so I am just attaching my Snapshot image from word file.

[image]